# EntityQuery get contents which were not modified

Tags: database

I'm writing a very basic query to get the count of contents which were not modified. The logic I'm applying here is simple too, just check if **created = changed**

The SQL query is pretty straightforward too.

```
SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM node_field_data WHERE type = 'my_content_type' AND created = changed
```

However getting this into EntityQuery syntax seems to be a bit difficult.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
           ->condition('status', 1)
           ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
           ->condition('created', 'changed', '='); //Need help here

$not_updated = $query->count()->execute();
```

Comment: The closest to finding a solution I've got is by using \Drupal::database() instead. $query = \Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 't')->condition('type', 'my_content_type')->where('t.changed = t.created');
$count = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField(); This surely works but is it possible to use entityQuery instead

Comment: Thanks sonfd for sharing the post. It talks about using \Drupal::database(), which is the same solution I'm currently using and posted in my comment